# Jquery ajax load comment without page refresh in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm developing a post comment system with PHP CodeIgniter framework.When a user comment for a post-it didn't get loaded without page refresh. Here is my ajax code.

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    // check to see which events this comment already has
    var events = $._data( this, 'events' ).keypress;

    // Try to find if keypress has already been registered
    // registering it twice causes duplicate comments

    var hasEvents = false;
    for(var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
        if(events[i].namespace == "") {
            hasEvents = true;
        }
    }

  if(!hasEvents) {
   $.ajax({
   url: global_base_url + 'feed/post_comment/' + id,
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
     comment: comment,
     csrf_test_name: global_hash,
     page: global_page,
     hide_prev: hide_prev
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(msg) {

     if (msg.error) {
       alert(msg.error_msg);
       return;
     }
     $('#feed-comments-spot-' + id).html(msg.content);
     $('#feed-comments-' + id).html(msg.comments);
   }
 });
}
```

My form code is:

```
<div class="feed-comment-area"  id="feed-comment-<?php echo $r->ID ?>">
```

Comment: Can you add your complete HTML code, especially the submit button?

Comment: "Enter" is submit here which calls the js file

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and also the JS where this `$.ajax` is getting used.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Where is your HTML? a Simple div is not a form!

Comment: Make sure dynamically created ids in html and js matches

Comment: are you using csrf token for this?

Comment: The comment loads only for recent posts as soon as user comment not for old post